# CInt Configure Script: Syntax error at left parenthesis

Tags: shell, array, configure

I am trying to install [CInt](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint). When running `./configure`, I get the following error:

```
./configure: 23: ./configure: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Here is the relevant section of `configure`:

```
# configure settings to build CINT

ARCHS=(linux linuxicc macgcc djgpp cygwin mingw mwerks hpux aix msvc7 msvc8 solaris solarisgcc)
```

What is wrong with the above syntax?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem. I am having the exact same issue as you, but the solution provided by jordanm doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @theJollySim Checking again now, it seems I never resolved the problem. I unchecked jordanm's answer, as it doesn't seem to be working now. I did get as far as being able to create a Makefile, but I don't think my modifications to ./configure were doing the right thing, so it doesn't build. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/djg123/aa86e15551ca2e3d1940) of my modified ./configure, I described what I did on lines 12, 16, and 28.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with that syntax if the shell supports arrays. Most likely the script starts with `#!/bin/sh` and wrongly uses specific shell features such as bash. If the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, change it to `#!/bin/bash` and report the problem to the `CINT` developers.

Answer (score 0):

Please change line 16
`|| (sh $0 __have_the_proper_shell@ "$*") \`

to
`|| (bash $0 __have_the_proper_shell@ "$*") \`

and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Through trial and error I've determined that by commenting all of the preceding lines (before line 24), related to testing for valid shell and inserting `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning will make it work.

Comment: this doe not provide any information what would not be provided in the other answer.